# Misunderstanding of JavaScript closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm new to JavaScript, and am having a problem understanding this code:

```
function addProperty(o) {
   var value;

   o["get"] = function()  { return value; }
   o["set"] = function(v) { value = v; }
}

var a = {};
addProperty(a);
var b = {};
addProperty(b);

a.set(4);
b.set(5);
print("a is " + a.get() + "; b is " + b.get());
```

This prints (in v8/d8) `a is 4; b is 5`. If I comment out the `var value;` line, I get `a is 5; b is 5`. Where is the 'value' object, and why are there two of them? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the "why are there two of them" part of the question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Object 'a' has a value associated with it, which holds integer '4', and object 'b' has a value associated with it, which holds integer '5'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `value` variable is local to `addProperty`. The first time `addProperty` is called, a new `value` is created, over which both of the functions close. The second time `addProperty` is called, a second `value` is created over which two new functions close.

Removing `var` creates a *global* `value` on the `window` object that is shared by all of the functions.

Maybe you mean to do this:

```
function createPropertyMgr() {
    var value;
    return function(o) {
       o["get"] = function()  { return value; }
       o["set"] = function(v) { value = v; }
    }
}

var addProperty = createPropertyMgr();
```

This new `addProperty` function closes over one `value` no matter how many times it's called. I'm not sure I understand the use case, but that should demonstrate the difference.

Comment: +1 There is one `value` in *source*, but two in *memory*. This seems to be the confusion of the OP.

Comment: So, it creates a copy of value var on every addProperty call. But, how binds it to the argument object?

Comment: @TomasNarros: the same way. Formal parameters, function declarations and variables declared with `var` are all part of the 'Activation Object' and that is, which is copied over to create a lexical closure.

Comment: @TomasNarros - Each time `addProperty` is called a new pair of `get/set` functions are created for the object passed in that close over a new `value`.

Comment: Ok, I get it - thanks. I'm just about to ask another question, which is what prompted this one, about encapsulation in general.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't explicitly declare a variable inside a function, its scope is assumed as global. i.e. in your second case, since you have not declared `value` explicitly as local to the function `addProperty()`, it gets treated as global.

But when you do declare it explicitly inside a function, it becomes local to the function. Every time the function is invoked a new copy of the function local variable is created on the stack (and importantly it stays there in the stack as long as there is a reference to it)